# I want to create a bootstrap popover with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a popover using bootstrap and placing dynamic content from PHP into it (HTML code).

I have the following code:

```
<a class="psprn"
href="'.$prnUrl.'"
data-toggle="popover"
data-content="'.$prnName.'"
data-pspicture="'.$prnImage.'"
data-psrank="'.$prnRank.'"
data-psvideo="'.$prnVideos.'">'.$prnName.'</a>
```

This anchor its a link for users, so I can have 2,3,4 (and so on) users.
This anchor is placed on a 'foreach' Yii app, so he have dynamic content (to have specific image, link, rank, video, content).

I have this js code:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').hover(function () {
    var psrank = $(this).attr("data-psrank");
    var psvideo = $(this).attr("data-psvideo");
    var pspicture = $(this).attr("data-pspicture");
    var pscontent = $(this).attr("data-content");
//        console.log(psrank);
//        console.log(psvideo);
//        console.log(pspicture);
//        console.log(pscontent);

    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({       
        trigger: 'hover',
        template: 
            '<div class="ps-placeholder>'+
                '<div class="picture">'+
                    '<img src="prnImage">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="footy">'+
                    '<p>$prnName</p>'+
                    '<span>Rank: $prnRank &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Videos: $prnVideos</span>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>',
    });
});
```

But something goes wrong. I cannot place the values of data-attributes on the tooltip template.

Infos:

- Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.4
- jQuery v2.2.3

Answer (score 1):

What you currently have won't work. Your variable names get interpreted as strings. You need to replace your `"` with ` symbol, then you're able to use `${someVariable}` within your string.

Here is a basic example.

```js
//Your dynamic content
var catImage = "http://n-z.tv/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/cat-1024x683.jpg";
var message = "Hey this is some dynamic content";
var title = "Some Dynamic Content"

//Create the string and insert it into the body (or the "template" for you)
document.body.innerHTML = `
<div>
  <h3>${title}</h3>
  <img src="${catImage}"/>
  <p>${message}</p>
</div>
`
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

You could take this a bit further by creating a function that handles this.

```js
let generateDynamicContent = function(title, imageSrc, message){
    return `<div>
      <h3>${title}</h3>
      <img src="${imageSrc}"/>
      <p>${message}</p>
    </div>
    `
}

let dynamic = document.getElementById("dynamic");
let container = document.getElementById("container");

let imageSrcs = [
  "https://404store.com/2017/08/19/cat-wallpaper-1024.jpg",
  "https://fanparty.ru/fanclubs/cats/gallery/534626_cats.jpg",
  "http://n-z.tv/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/cat-1024x683.jpg"
];

let counter = 0;
dynamic.addEventListener("click", function(){

    let content = generateDynamicContent(
      `Dynamic title #${++counter}`, 
      imageSrcs[counter%imageSrcs.length],
      `Dynamic content #${counter}`
    )
    container.innerHTML = content;

});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<button id="dynamic">Click me for dynamic content</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```